# javascript - constructor - __proto__

Tags: javascript, constructor

I am learning javascript and the following code confuses me.

```
//a constructor function
function Person() {
}

//creating object person1
var person1 = new Person();

//changing the prototype of Person
Person.prototype = {};

//creating object person2
var person2 = new Person();
```

Now, `person1.constructor` still remains `function Person()`, whereas `person2.constructor` gives `function Object()`.

If I understand correctly, `person1.constructor` works by `person1.__proto__.constructor` and `person1.__proto__` points to `Person.prototype`

In this case, shouldn't `person1.constructor` be `function Object()` instead of `function Person()`?

Comment: Well, `person1.__proto__` points to the value `Person.prototype` had **before** you assigned a new value to it. And at that point (before the reassignment) `Person.prototype.constructor` referenced `Person`. If you do `person1.__proto__ === person2.__proto__` you will get `false`, meaning both instances have different prototypes.

Comment: The internal `[[Prototype]]` is set when the instance is created. Changing the constructor's prototype to a different object later doesn't change existing instances (which seems to be the point of the code). ;-)

Comment: Thanks guys for the reply, I read the other post RobG has mentioned. Its clear to me now.